# call stored procedure block in an IF block in Snowflake

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to put a CALL block into an IF block like so:

```
    if (CALL called_proc(:upper_name) = 'Error') THEN
       RAISE :proc_exception;
    END IF;
```

The separate procedure 'called_proc' will be passed the :upper_name variable and will check whether it's got a semi colon or not like so:

```
    IF ((SELECT CONTAINS (:proc_variable, ';'))=TRUE) THEN
        RETURN 'Error';
    END IF;
```

If it has a semi colon, it will return 'Error' then the IF block will raise the proc_exception.

The if block above is obviously wrong so I was wondering what's the right way to have a CALL stored proc block inside an IF block.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
create or replace procedure called_proc(upper_name varchar(100))
returns varchar
language SQL
as
$$
BEGIN
  IF ((SELECT CONTAINS (:upper_name, ';'))=TRUE) THEN
    RETURN 'Error';
  END IF;
  RETURN 'Success';
END;
$$;
```

When I call this Stored Procedure:

```
call called_proc('test;1');
```

I get:

```
CALLED_PROC
Error
```

Then I used this stored procedure to do what you wanted:

```
DECLARE
  my_exception EXCEPTION (-20002, 'Raised MY_EXCEPTION.');
  msg varchar;
BEGIN
  CALL called_proc('test;1') INTO :msg;
  IF (msg = 'Error') THEN
    RAISE my_exception;
  END IF;
END;
```

This gives me:

[image]

Of course you can add this block into another stored procedure if you want.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much! I'm still learning SQL and this is really helpful! Thanks again